# django error reporting request url - how to use this locally?

Tags: django

I have a django project which used the normal email admins on an unhandled exception when debug is set to False. ie in production.

I normally just review the error message and the stack trace.  However I clicked on the `request url` link, which managed to recreate the error on the prouduction site (which then fired off another email).

What is this request url? Does it recreate the full http request (including the session etc..) which resulted in the original error?
Can I get the link to point to a local version of the site? (As after fixing a previous error clicking on the earlier request url has manged to create a recent error that we have been unable to reproduce, so it would be good to recreate this locally so it can be debugged.

Comment: No, the request URL link does not create the http request that caused the error. It is just the URL. It should be possible to [customise the error reporting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/error-reporting/#custom-error-reports) to change the domain, but it's not as simple as changing a setting.

Comment: ok thanks for confirming